# Send as Attachment from Citrix server -> Launch Outlook on local workstation

Tags: email, exchange, citrix

A system I'm working on has a simple report generating feature. It creates a doc-file, saves it to disk and launches the file in Word.

Recently we got a complaint from one of our customers. After the file had been opened in Word, they used the *Send as Attachment* feature, but this gave them some kind of error (something with *No profile found*). They asked us if there were something wrong with the "e-mail integration" in our system. They have our system running on a Citrix server without Outlook (or any other e-mail program) installed... :rolleyes:

They use Outlook with Exchange on their local workstations, and they do not want to have Outlook installed on the Citrix server (because of the big memory/resource footprint, they say), so they asked us for advice on what to do.

Bear in mind that I have *no* knowledge of Citrix what so ever, so I might be overlooking some very obvious things here. My first idea was that we could just have them install some light-weight e-mail client on the Citrix server (such as i.Scribe, or perhaps even Thunderbird). But then I started to wonder if it were possible to have Citrix use Outlook on the local workstation instead.

***So, question:***
Is it possible to configure Citrix so that *Send as Attachment* features (e.g. from within Word) will be redirected to the local installation on the workstation?

Any other tips to get around this without too much trouble is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this will also depend on the configuration of your citrix environment, specifically in terms of security.  Understandably you may not want outlook on these machines.

**If drive redirection is enabled have the user copy to the document back to their local pc.**  Considering this is a pretty obvious option I would assume this is not enabled in citrix.

**Map a network drive on the citrix server that is also mapped on the local workstations.**  You can use this drive to copy files back and forth, or script a solution to do this.

**Use a script in conjunction with blat.exe to email the file where needed.**  In this scenario you would create a new right click feature under Send To -> My Email.  With the script you could have the user type the email address they wanted to send to, and it could send through an available smtp server.

*I am not including a blat script as it is pretty straight forward and would likely need modification for your environment.  http://www.blat.net/*

As for the Word send as attachment the only option I could think of would be to setup outlook express as an outbound setup only.  Ideally this should be just disabled via GPO but I am unable to find that option.

Hope this helps you.